# Is a definite article necessary in "I’ll definitely get the first place."?

Tags: definite-article, collocations

Consider the following passage from a webnovel:

> He felt a gush of gratitude in his heart. He did not say anything, but deep down inside he decided, *This time I must not let them down, I’ll definitely get the first place!*

I'm concerned about the `the first place` part. Internet has ambiguous information about if there should be `the` before `first` because there's a widely used `in first place` construction that adds to the confusion.

So, should there be `the` before `first` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct—omitting 'the' is more natural. I cannot think of a grammatical reason as to why—perhaps it is idiomatic.